# function to get data from database

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to build a function that get data from database and return it, then i would like to call this function into a while.

i do this function but give me some problems when i call it from a while:

```
public function getAllUsers() {

    // if database connection opened
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {

        // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
        $query = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
        $query->execute();

        // get result row (as an object)
        return $query->fetchObject();

    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

and these is the way i would like to call the function:

```
while($row = $users->getAllUsers()) {
    echo "User name: ".$row->user_name."<br>User ID: ".$row->user_id;
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: "*but give me some problems*", like what exactly? What's the desired output versus what are you currently getting? Do you get any kind of errors, and if no - are you *looking* for errors?

Comment: You have to pay attention at your own code. You have named you function as `getAllUsers`, but - before returning data - you comment: `// get result row`. If you use `PDO`, your function doesn't return all user, but **only one**; to return all the user, you have to use `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problem in your code:

1. The `getAllUsers()` method return only the first record of query, not all;
2. even if you fix this, your `while` loop - as noted in another answer - never ends, because retrieve infinitely a result.

To fix it, you have to change your code in this way:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
    (...)
    // get all rows (as an object)
    return $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
    (...)
}
```

and then perform a `foreach` loop instead of the `while` one:

```
foreach( $users->getAllUsers() as $row ) {
    (...)
}
```

Alternative: you can return the `$query` object and fetch-it out of the method:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
    (...)
    // return the query:
    return $query;
    (...)
}

$rows = $users->getAllUsers();
while( $row = $rows->fetchObject() ) {
    echo "User name: ".$row->user_name."<br>User ID: ".$row->user_id;
}
```

The first solution is more congruent and pretty, the second can more performative on **very** large number of rows returned by the query

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is getting all users, and then loop over all your users and echo some information about them. Your function `getAllUsers()` retrieves all users with your SQL query. However, your while loop executes your function many times, each time getting the entire user list.

Instead, execute your function once, get the result from it, and then loop over the result.

```
$userlist = $users->getAllUsers();

while($row = $userlist->getRow()) { //Im not sure what the function is to get a row in the framework you're using.
    echo "User name: ".$row->user_name."<br>User ID: ".$row->user_id;
}
```

[Look up how a while loop works](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp)

The predicate of a while loop (`$row = $users->getAllUsers()`) is run each iteration, so calling a function in the predicate also executes that function each iteration.